# Help with Nvidia driver install and --kernel-source-path

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I am working in RHEL 7 and I need to install the Nvidia driver for my GPU. I know I have downloaded the right driver from the Nvidia website. I have also installed the linux kernel packages and those are located in `/usr` as in `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h`

It's become clear to me that the Nvidia driver is taking a path and then adding it's own path to it to look for the kernel file. If I run the driver install with:

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.126.02.run --kernel-source-path /usr/include
```

Nvidia says that `/usr/include/include/linux/kernel.h` is an invalid path (note the extra `include`, this is the part that Nvidia adds). OK, no problem, so then I run

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.126.02.run --kernel-source-path /usr/
```

And that tells me that `/usr/` is not a valid entry for that parameter.

I'm stuck as to what to do next. Is it OK to move the files to another directory? Or is this a known issue with Nvidia? Google searches turned up nothing on this specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/include` is the path for include files *for user-space programs*. The place where RHEL `kernel-devel` RPMs place the headers for compiling *kernel modules* is actually `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)`.

The Nvidia installer should actually be able to auto-detect this, because there should be a symbolic link at `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` pointing there.

So, make sure that the `kernel-devel` RPM matching the exact kernel version you're running is installed, then try this one:

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.126.02.run --kernel-source-path /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)
```

Or just omit the `--kernel-source-path` option altogether.

As the name of the option suggests, it's supposed to be pointed at a directory hierarchy whose structure matches the root directory of a standard Linux kernel source tree. It will have its own `include` sub-directory, exactly as the installer is expecting.